# usb serial not work

Tags: usb

Good evening.
I am using ubuntu 22.04 lts 64bit.
I want to program an esp8266 board with arduino ide. The card is equipped with the CP2102 cip but the system does not load the cp210X.ko driver, nor usbserial.ko and therefore I do not see the comXX port. The driver is present in the kernel folder cell associated with my version 5.19.0-41.
With ubuntu version 18.04 lts and kernel 4.x it worked.

```
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. Integrated Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 8564:4000 Transcend Information, Inc. microSD/SD/CF UHS-II Card Reader [RDF8, RDF9]
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 2109:0813 VIA Labs, Inc. VL813 Hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2109:0813 VIA Labs, Inc. VL813 Hub
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 1058:25a1 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. Elements / My Passport
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 13d3:3503 IMC Networks 
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 222a:0001 ILI Technology Corp. Multi-Touch Screen
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 05e3:0605 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 0781:556b SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Edge
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 2109:2813 VIA Labs, Inc. VL813 Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2109:2813 VIA Labs, Inc. VL813 Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Watch `sudo journalctl  --follow` as you connect the device. Does `id` show you're in the additional group (probably `tty`) as the `/dev` entry?